# Matching pattern to end of line

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get some in-line comments from a text file and need some help with the expression.

```
this comes before selection
this is on the same line %% this is the first group and it can have any character /[{3$5!+-p
here is some more text in the middle
this stuff is also on a line with a comment %% this is the second group of stuff !@#%^()<>/~`
this goes after the selections
```

I am trying to get everything that follows %%\s+. Here is what I tried:

> %%\s+(.*)$

But that matches all text following the first %%. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use [`RegexOptions.Multiline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Actually, no need using `$`. `%%\s+(.*)` is enough.

Comment: @stribizhev Yeah, if the dot isn't matching newline then how did having the `$` result in matching from the first %% to the end of the line?  I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @juharr: It is probably the result of using `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag. The full code is not provided by OP, but it is quite clear where and why the issue occurs.

Comment: @juharr you nailed it! can you post the answer please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most engines default to the dot does not match newlines
*AND* not multi-line mode.

That means `%%\s+(.*)$` should not match unless it finds
`%%` on the last line in the string.

Instead of trying to fight it, use inline modifiers `(?..)` that
*override* external switches.

Use `(?-s)%%\s+(.*)` which takes *off* dot all

Answer (score 0):

Since `.` matches any character but a newline by default, you needn't use `$`:

```
%%\s+(.*)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%25%25%5Cs%2B(.*)&i=this%20comes%20before%20selection%0D%0Athis%20is%20on%20the%20same%20line%20%25%25%20this%20is%20the%20first%20group%20and%20it%20can%20have%20any%20character%20%2F%5B%7B3%245!%2B-p%0D%0Ahere%20is%20some%20more%20text%20in%20the%20middle%0D%0Athis%20stuff%20is%20also%20on%20a%20line%20with%20a%20comment%20%25%25%20this%20is%20the%20second%20group%20of%20stuff%20!%40%23%25%5E()%3C%3E%2F%7E%60%0D%0Athis%20goes%20after%20the%20selections)

Explanation:

- `%%` - two literal `%` symbols
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace
- `(.*)` - 0 or more any characters other than a newline (captured into Group 1)

[image]

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/0TaCZd):

```
var s = "THE_STRING";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, @"%%\s+(.*)")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(p=>p.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
```